# Is there another alternative to DataArray.sel(time = slice(x, y)) in xarray?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

For some reason, the DataArray.sel(time = slice(x, y)) is working for me without any problem for the months of January to June, where x and y are both equal to values ranging from 1 for January to 6 for June. However, this method is not working for July to December. I have checked the input data, which is a netCDF4 file and it is not corrupted. Therefore, I am looking for an alternative to use instead of DataArray.sel(time = slice(x, y)) in xarray to extract the data for the months of July to December.

The code is as follows:

```
import xarray as xr
td = xr.open_dataset(r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\misc\netcdf_to_geotiff\ECLIPSEv5_monthly_patterns.nc')
td_agr = td.agr
td_agrtime = td_agr.sel(time = slice('1', '1'))
```

which gives the output:

```
In [7]: td_agrtime
Out[7]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'agr' (time: 1, lat: 360, lon: 720)>
[259200 values with dtype=float64]
Coordinates:
* lat      (lat) float64 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 -88.25 ... 88.75 89.25 
89.75
* lon      (lon) float64 -179.8 -179.2 -178.8 -178.2 ... 178.8 179.2 
179.8
* time     (time) int32 1
Attributes:
long_name:  Monthly weights - Agriculture (animals, rice, soil)
sector:     Agriculture (animals, rice, soil)
```

If the 1 is changed to 7 in the code as follows:

```
td_agrtime = td_agr.sel(time = slice('7', '7')
```

the output is:

```
In [7]: td_agrtime
Out[9]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'agr' (time: 6, lat: 360, lon: 720)>
[1555200 values with dtype=float64]
Coordinates:
* lat      (lat) float64 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 -88.25 ... 88.75 89.25 
89.75
* lon      (lon) float64 -179.8 -179.2 -178.8 -178.2 ... 178.8 179.2 
179.8
* time     (time) int32 7 8 9 10 11 12
Attributes:
long_name:  Monthly weights - Agriculture (animals, rice, soil)
sector:     Agriculture (animals, rice, soil)
```

Comment: `However, this method is not working for July to December` In what way, exactly, is it not working?  Do you get an error?  Do you get unexpected results?

Comment: I am getting unexpected results. If I type DataArray.sel(time = slice(7, 7)), I am getting the data for July to December. However, I should be getting the data only for July. This is not the case for January to June.

Comment: I don't think we can really help unless you post the full code, including how the array is built.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: I am not sure of the reason for this behavior, but it seems that `.isel()` (select by integer index) would work here, since your time values are just integers anyway.

Comment: Indeed `.isel()` seems to work. Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Robert Davy for his comment. The answer is to use `.isel()`, instead of `.sel()`.